# When tomcat starts up, it takes wrong JAVA version that is 1.5 instead of 1.6

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have installed JAVA 1.6 on Redhat Linux 4 and wanted to function it with tomcat 5.5 but i am facing the below issue:
When I am stopping the tomcat server it is taking JAVA 1.6 , but when I am bringing it up , it is taking JAVA 1.5(this one is pre-installed and currently working).
I am not understanding where i am missing. Please help me on this. I am really naive but hope to understand these things through you.

Points:

1. Server has already installed JAVA 1.5 which is currently working. I want to change the JAVA to 1.6 from 1.5
2. JAVA 6 has been installed in the directory --> /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/
3. I have only changed tomcat start up file JAVA_HOME variable to 
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/
4. when i am stopping the server, it shows,
   Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/
5. When I am starting the tomcat server, it shows,
   Using JRE_HOME:       /apps/UTCinet-WK/jdk1.5.0_03

many thanks in advance

> java -version

```
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

> and when i stop the server, it shows:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /apps/xxxx/tomcat/xxx/xxxx
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /apps/xxxx/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apps/xxxx/tomcat/xxxx/xxxx/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/
Confirming shutdown completion - 5 xxxxonds..
```

> and when i start the server, it shows:

```
Setting environment (DEV) from hostname. at /apps/xxxx/scripts/get_env.pl line 18.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /apps/xxxx/tomcat/xxxx/xxxx
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /apps/xxxx/jakarta-tomcat-5.5.9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apps/xxxx/tomcat/xxxx/xxxx/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       /apps/xxxx/jdk1.5.0_03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following outputs:
1. `echo $JAVA_HOME` 
2. `echo $PATH` 
3. `java -version` 
4. Check `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` file

And if you're starting your tomcat via a service call (and not via startup.sh), check that script as well to see if the JAVA_HOME is set to something there.

Usually, fixing the `setenv.sh` file should do the trick.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have put the outputs i am getting on the issue description. Also, when i am hitting all the echo commands, i am getting nothing. And also i do not find setenv.sh file in $CATALINA_HOME/bin/ . thanks in advance. Please let me know if you want anything else.

Comment: What does the get_env.pl script do? It doesn't sound like standard tomcat file. Is there any customization in place? If there is, make sure that file gets picked up both by startup and shutdown scripts of tomcat.

Comment: i am not sure what get_env.pl is doing. but you can be assured that the same get_env.pl file is using for both stopping and starting the server. I have checked that. And yes of course the server is heavily customized. Many thanks. Please advise

Comment: Heavily customized? I believe you'll have to follow the start up script to see who is setting the path. If it's standard tomcat, or something we can do in our machines, it'd be easy for us to answer. It's a lot difficult to assume and guide you here.

Comment: Hi prabugp , actually i have been able to solve the issue. The Issue was in the startup script JAVA_HOME variable was explicitely defined to the old JAVA directory, the same thing was not in the stop script.So, I have changed the startup script so that it can connect to newer version of JAVA and it is working now :) many thanks for your help. Many thanks :)

Comment: Cool. If this post helped you solve the problem, please mark the answer as accepted. Helps others who stumble upon here.

Comment: But I just have one more question, why can't i see anything when i hit echo $JRE_HOME or echo $JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: Because they are not set in the env. They might have put the java dir directly in the path.

Comment: Okey. Got your point :) thank you. But when i installed JAVA 6 on the application server, i didn't explicitly set its path to the PATH, but i see it is set there. Does it automatically happen?

Comment: also check `$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh`. (`$CATALINA_BASE` versus `$CATALINA_HOME`). In general, the `$CATALINA_BASE` version is not required.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have anything spurious going on in the $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh file.  That's the "preferred" place to set things like JAVA_HOME anyway.